# Dynamic named range with blanks have formulas

Tags: excel

I have a dynamic named range below which has blanks with formulas which are updated with data when rows adjacent have dat. I would like to only have filled rows and leave out the blanks with formula.
The blanks are always below not in between or on top

Any help on how to do this is highly appreciated.

Here is the formula i found on internet so far but include even blanks with formulas.

=OFFSET(DataBase!$Y$17,1,0,COUNTA("*",DataBase!Y17:Y9999,-1),1)

Comment: Are the filled cell all concentrated on the top of the list? Will `=OFFSET(DataBase!$Y$17,1,0, AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(DataBase!Y17:Y9999)/(DataBase!Y17:Y9999<>"")-ROW(DataBase!$Y$17),1),1)` be enouth?

Comment: Yes filled cell on top are these two different codes?

Comment: You're welcome. If they are all on top this formulas should also work: `=OFFSET($Y$17,1,0,ROWS(Y17:Y9999)-COUNTBLANK(Y17:Y9999))`. It should be lighter than the previous one and easier to understand/edit. Still it won't work if there are blank cells in between the data. In such case the previous one shuld still work.